# Where can I ask question about gmail?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which stack exchange site make it possible to ask such a questions?

Comment: What's the nature of your question about that product?  There are all sorts of things that you could ask about Gmail, relating to many radically different topics.

Comment: I want to know - how is it possible to have one username for gmail for example "John 1" and the same user for youtube but with other name, lets say "John 2". So if I send an email it will be from John1 and if I post comments on youtube videos etc. John2 will be visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try [Web Apps StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Web Applications Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of
> web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other **website which behaves like an application**
> - Bookmarklets
> - Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Also have a look at [gmail tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/gmail/info):

> For questions about the Gmail service as accessed by a desktop or mobile browser. Questions about native smartphone apps are off-topic on Web Apps.

Visiting some [frequent questions on gmail tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail?sort=frequent) may be useful.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Asked there https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111448/same-user-with-different-name-for-gmail-and-youtube