# Which site should I post on regarding advanced Gmail filtering?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, email, site-crossover

I have an issue with one of my emails where it gets too many spam emails. The emails clearly have me BCC'd as the recipient email is always David{*some string of characters*}@aol.com and the CC email is David{*some different string of characters*}@aol.com.

I believe it is possible via Google's app scripting to write an advanced filter to delete these emails with this pattern. The issue is, I'm not sure what site to write this on.

My first two thoughts would be Overflow or Super User, but usually Overflow wants some first attempt at coding to critique and I have no clue how to approach this. As for Super User, my experience is that they work mostly with the Windows system and programs, and this question might not be appropriate.

---

This is not a duplicate of [Which site answers questions on Google services?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250953/) because the answer to that question is incomplete an obsolete.

By one side suggest to ask question about Gmail in Web Applications but Gmail is a complex service. For one side is an email service offering IMAP /POP3 / SMTP protocols, it is a cross-platform app, its a service for email administratrors, can be used by programmers / developers, etc. Questions about using the Web app *might* be on-topic in [webapps.se]. The answer doesn't mentions about the focus of this quesiton that is about Gmail filtering. It doesn't clarify about using Google Apps Script for this purpose.

Comment: Related: [Seeking Stack Exchange site to post questions regarding using company services like Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340866/289691), [Where can I ask question about gmail?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302831/289691)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check out [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). [[gmail]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) has 4,321 questions [[gmail-filters]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-filters) has 472 questions, but you might try searching https://stackexchange.com

By the way, in Gmail a filter is a built-in feature. You might be thinking on using code to automatically delete email messages periodically, this will require of a related feature, search.

Related from Web Applications

- [Matching Gmail filters on BCC mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31746/88163)
- [How to create a filter with bcc or cc](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/127694/88163)

Related from Stack Overflow

- [How to extract all From, To, Cc, Bcc emails from Gmail to store in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44722037/1595451)

---

Most questions about **using** Gmail in the Web (by using a web browser) are on-topic in [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Overall questions about Gmail might be on-topic while the question doesn't make too much emphasis on caveats of:

- installable app,
- email clients,
- email protocols ([IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol), [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), and [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol))
- Gmail API,
- [Google Apps Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol),
- "too localized" uses cases (requires an answer that will not be helpful for anyone else)

do not go too deep on how the Gmail algorithms internally works.

Questions about Google Apps Script might be on-topic in [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) while the question be about about using it to create user defined functions like scripts, i.e. scripts for personal use or to be shared with small groups, not requiring advanced programming skills or engineering knowledge.

Questions about Google Apps Script or the Gmail API might be on-topic in **Stack Overflow** while they are focused on *programming*. [[gmail]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) has 10,511 questions

Questions about Gmail might be on-topic in **[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)** while they be focused on using software and hardware for personal / domestic use, no matter of the operating system, it could be Windows, Mac, Linux, etc. with exception of smart phones, smart devices among others. Questions about scripts to be executed locally, i.e. writing scripts for batch files, might be on-topic. [[gmail]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) has 1,329 questions

- You might use an email client to handle your Gmail mailbox through IMAP, i.e., Microsoft [Outlook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook) you could set a rule to delete email messages.

Questions about Gmail might be on-topic in **[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)** while they be about using an desktop Ubuntu applications. [[gmail]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gmail) has 275 questions.

Questions about Gmail might be on-topic in **[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour)** while they be about using Gmail by using an Android app. [[gmail]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) has 674 questions.

Questions about Gmail might be on-topic in **[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)** while they be about using Gmail by using a macOS or an iOS app. [[gmail]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) has 707 questions.